# Save file from usb onto computer using command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I have written a script to run on a server. I have access the the Windows server itself, but it does not have a *GUI* - it is just a command terminal. The script I need is saved on a USB Thumb drive, and I am struggling to copy it onto the server (which I have access to).

I have tried:

```
mkdir myFolder
copy script.txt C:\myFolder
```

In response to this, the server prints

> Successfully Copied

But when I try

```
cd C:\myFolder
```

I get an invalid directory name error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was editing my post with what I tried..

Comment: I've voted to reopen. After your edit, it's a valid, reasonable question (which is why I answered it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create the directory, and then change to that drive and directory after copying. For instance, if your USB drive is `G:`

Change to drive `G:`, create the folder on `C:`, and then copy the file

```
G:
md C:\TargetFolder
xcopy file.txt C:\TargetFolder
```

Then change to drive `C:` and make `TargetFolder` the current directory

```
C:
cd \TargetFolder
```

or, in one command:

```
cd /d C:\TargetFolder
```

Or, if you're already on drive C: to start

```
md \TargetFolder
cd \TargetFolder
xcopy G:\file.txt
```